# Magento: Get all updated cart items data in AJAX response

Tags: ajax, magento, magento-1.7, cart

My Cart is looking like this with popup window:

[image]

I am updating multiple configurable items in cart with custom options at a time by AJAX Call.

But I am not able to get all items data back to AJAX response.

I am getting just 1st itemPrice and rowTotal. For remaining items itemPrice and rowTotal are set to 0.

**Code:**

```
public function updateItemOptionsAction()
{
    $cartData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cart');
    Mage::log($cartData);
    if (is_array($cartData)) {
        $result = array();
        $result['data'] = array();
        foreach ($cartData as $index => $data) {
            $cart   = $this->_getCart();
            $params = $data;
            $id = (int)$data['id'];

            if (!isset($params['options'])) {
                $params['options'] = array();
            }
            $result['data'][$index] = array();
            $oldQty = null;
            $kitType = $params['efk_kType'];
            $params['super_attribute'] = array($data['sAttr']=>$kitType);
            unset($params['sAttr']);
            $stock = null;
            try {
                if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($params['product']);
                    $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null, $product);
                    foreach($childProducts as $cProd){
                        if($cProd->getKitType() == $kitType){
                            $stock = intval(Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($cProd)->getQty());
                        }
                    }
                    if(intval($params['qty']) > $stock){
                        $oldQty = intval($params['qty']);
                        $params['qty'] = $stock;
                        $result['data'][$index]['revised'] = true;
                    }

                    $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                        array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                    );
                    $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
                }

                $quoteItem = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemById($id);
                if (!$quoteItem) {
                    Mage::throwException($this->__('Quote item is not found.'));
                }

                //Its going to infinity loop duwe to Varien Object need to check later
                //$item = $cart->updateItem($id, new Varien_Object($params));
                $item = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->updateItem($id, $params);

                if (is_string($item)) {
                    Mage::throwException($item);
                }
                if ($item->getHasError()) {
                    Mage::throwException($item->getMessage());
                }
                Mage::log('hi2');

                $related = $params['related_product'];
                if (!empty($related)) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
                }

                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_item_complete',
                    array('item' => $item, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
                );
                $cart->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->init();

                if (!Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                    if (!Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                        Mage::log('hi4');
                        $result['success'] = true;
                        if($oldQty > $item->getQty()){
                            $message = $this->__('%s has been revised due to stock limitations. You may proceed with the order for the revised quantity.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($item->getProduct()->getName()));
                        }else{
                            $message = $this->__('%s was updated in your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($item->getProduct()->getName()));
                        }
                        $result['data'][$index]['message'] = $message;
                        $result['data'][$index]['itemId'] = $item->getId();
                        $result['data'][$index]['itemPrice'] = Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($item->getCalculationPrice());
                        $result['data'][$index]['qty'] = $item->getQty();
                        $result['data'][$index]['rowTotal'] = Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($item->getRowTotal());
                    }
                }

            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $result['success'] = false;
                $result['data'][$index]['success'] = 'qty';
                $result['data'][$index]['message'] = $e->getMessage();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $result['success'] = false;
                $result['data'][$index]['message'] = $e->getMessage();
                $result['data'][$index]['secondMessage'] = $this->__('Cannot update the item.');
            }
        }



        $result['data']['grandTotal'] = Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal());
        $result['data']['totalItems'] = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty();
        $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getTotals();
        $result['data']['subTotal'] = Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($totals['subtotal']->getValue());
        if(isset($totals['discount']) && $totals['discount']->getValue()){
            $result['data']['discount'] = Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($totals['discount']->getValue());
        }else{
            $result['data']['discount'] = Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice(0);
        }
    }
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}
```

**AJAX Response I'm getting**

```
{
    "data": {
        "1187": {
            "success": true,
            "message": "THREE PHASE SOLID STATE RELAY WITH ZVS was updated in your shopping cart.",
            "itemId": "1191",
            "itemPrice": "<span class=\"price\">20b9  3,799</span>",
            "qty": 1,
            "rowTotal": "<span class=\"price\">20b9  3,799</span>",
            "forLoop": "yes"
        },
        "1189": {
            "success": true,
            "message": "AUTO INTENSITY CONTROL OF STREET LIGHTS was updated in your shopping cart.",
            "itemId": "1193",
            "itemPrice": "<span class=\"price\">20b9  0</span>",
            "qty": 1,
            "rowTotal": "<span class=\"price\">20b9  0</span>",
            "forLoop": "yes"
        },
        "grandTotal": "<span class=\"price\">20b9  8,798</span>",
        "totalItems": 2,
        "subTotal": "<span class=\"price\">20b9  8,798</span>",
        "discount": "<span class=\"price\">20b9  0</span>"
    }
}
```

I am getting itemPrice and rowTotal for 2nd item as 0. Every time I am getting correct values for 1st item only. If i am update 5 items at a time (say for example) then i am getting correct values for 1st item and for remianing items i am getting 0's.

If i refresh cart once i get AJAX response, then it is showing itemPrice and rowTotal updated values correctly for all items.

**Note: 20b9 is HEX Code for Indian Rupee symbol**

Please point out where i am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are items being updated correctly in cart and you only getting wrong data in ajax response to re-populate the cart pop-up again ?

Answer (score 1):

You're working tooooo hard... try updating the items in the controller server side as you sort of are, saving the current quote... and then just have a controller method that loads the current .phtml and returns the html as json for the cart block, and replace the whole cart html block (div) with the new one.

At the end of your controller method

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody( json_encode(
array("html" => 
            Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/[[whatevertag_is_to_cart_div phtml block]]')->toHtml()
     )
);
```

Comment: sry i didn't get you. If possible expalin me with code. I am newbie to magento.

Comment: does it make sense now?